# How to toggle class without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to toggle a class onClick without jQuery. I wrote the script but it seems to me it wrong)
I need to add `--active` modificator to `menu__button` class

```
   <div class="grid__menu">
       <i class="material-icons md-48 menu__button">dashboard</i>
   </div>
```

and my JS ((

```
   (function () {
   var menuTag = ".grid__menu i";   
   var activeModificator = "--active";
   var className = 'menu__button';
   var menu_button = document.querySelector(menuTag);    

menu_button.onclick =function() {     
   if (menu_button.classList.contains(className)) {       
     document.querySelector(menuTag).classList.add(className +      activeModificator);
     document.querySelector(menuTag).classList.remove(className);
      } else if (menu_button.classList.contains(className+activeModificator)) {
    document.querySelector(menuTag).classList.add(className);
    document.querySelector(menuTag).classList.remove(className+activeModificator);       
    } else {
        return       
        }
    };    
 })();
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TsarS/ovzzz0vo/2/)

but what a right way?

Comment: How about `classList.toggle(class)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). `classList` has a built-in `toggle`, so:

```
menu_button.onclick = function() {
    menu_button.classList.toggle(className);
    menu_button.classList.toggle(className + activeModificator);
};
```